# How Apple APNS Feedback service works?

Tags: iphone, push, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, feedback

I am developing an ipad application which uses apple push notifications.I heard about feedback service in APNS which can give the information about devices uninstalled the application or devices reformatted the iOS.

I would like to know the complete details of what the APNS Feedback service offers?

Any reference document or links for how to implement the feedback service in sandbox environment is highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp implements a call to the feedback service.

Comment: This question needs to be reopened as links die fast at Apple. Why not just delete this question if it is too broad??? takes up space on the Internets.